# How to configure eslint file level rule in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have a js file starting with eslint rule like

```
/* eslint eqeqeq: ["error", "smart"] */
/* jshint -W069 */
var myMod = function() {
..
...
```

When I am opening this file in VS Code its underlining any error, how to correctly configure VS Code to pick up rule from the same file?

Comment: When you hover over the underlined code, there should be a tooltip. There you'll see who's reporting the error. If it's jshint, I suggest you disable jshint completely in the settings and use solely eslint.